# AssertionError when threading in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to run some simple threading in Python using:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(analysis("samplequery"))
t1.start()

other code runs in here

t1.join()
```

Unforunately I'm getting the error:

> "AssertionError: group argument must be none for now"

I've never implemented threading in Python before, so I'm a bit unsure as to what's going wrong. Does anyone have any idea what the problem is?

I'm not sure if it's relevant at all, but analysis is a method imported from another file.

I had one follow up query as well. Analysis returns a dictionary, how would I go about assigning that for use in the original method?

Thanks

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You want to specify the `target` keyword parameter instead:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=analysis("samplequery"))
```

You probably meant to make `analysis` the run target, but `'samplequery` the argument *when started*:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=analysis, args=("samplequery",))
```

The first parameter to `Thread()` is the `group` argument, and it currently only accepts `None` as the argument.

From the [`threading.Thread()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread):

> This constructor should always be called with keyword arguments. Arguments are:
>
> - *group* should be `None`; reserved for future extension when a `ThreadGroup` class is implemented.
> - *target* is the callable object to be invoked by the `run()` method. Defaults to `None`, meaning nothing is called.

Comment: This still passes the result of `analysis` to the Thread constructor, which is wrong unless the function returns a callable.

Comment: @g.d.d.c: Yeah, was getting to that. :-)

Comment: No problem, just making sure.  :)

Comment: That seems to fix the problem, thanks! How would I access the dictionary though, I'm still not entirely sure how to get to it?

Comment: @Incredidave: You need to communicate among your threads (main and sub threads), perhaps using a queue; see [python multithreading for dummies](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2846653) and any good threading and python tutorial.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Managed to get it working using a queue, thanks a lot for the help and links.

Comment: I had the same with the `Process()` constructor.

Comment: @ValentinGrégoire: yes, the [`multiprocessing.Process()` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) is deliberately modelled on the `threading.Thread()` class and has the name behaviour when it comes to the first argument.

Answer (score 9):

You need to provide the `target` attribute:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target = analysis, args = ('samplequery',))
```

Comment: and because positional arg can't be after keyword arg, you gotta provide the `args` attribute too.