# Solving group argument error in threading

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

I am using threading to download,convert videos and delete it. However, when I use threading, it gives me an error `AssertionError: group argument must be None for now`
Threading worked fine until 3 runs before but it is suddenly showing this error.

I thought the group argument was default None but I just added 'group = None' into the parameter. Now it shows an error saying `TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'group'`

```
def video_download(parent_file, url):
    #checking if it succeed or not for logging
    fail = []
    success = []
    #which number in the list the program is in
    check = 1

    #check if the url is playlist or single video
    if url.find("list") != -1:
        pl = Playlist(url)
        links = pl.parse_links()
        #length of list
        total = len(links)
        print("\n start download")
        for l in links:
            t1 = threading.Thread(l,target= download_multi, group = None, args=(l,check,parent_file,success,fail,total))
            t1.start()
            time.sleep(1)
            t2 = threading.Thread(target= download_multi, group = None, args=(l,check,parent_file,success,fail,total))
            t2.start()
            time.sleep(1)
            t3 = threading.Thread(target= download_multi, group = None, args=(l,check,parent_file,success,fail,total))
            t3.start()
            time.sleep(1)
            t1.join()
            t2.join()
            t3.join()
```

Error code without group = None

```
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2060, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2054, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1405, in run
    return self._exec(is_module, entry_point_fn, module_name, file, globals, locals)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1412, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/paulm/Desktop/Github/git/YoutubeDownloader/main.py", line 179, in <module>
    recieve_input()
  File "C:/Users/paulm/Desktop/Github/git/YoutubeDownloader/main.py", line 37, in recieve_input
    video_download(parent_file, url)
  File "C:/Users/paulm/Desktop/Github/git/YoutubeDownloader/main.py", line 102, in video_download
    t1 = threading.Thread(l,target= download_multi, args=(l,check,parent_file,success,fail,total))
  File "C:\Users\paulm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 786, in __init__
    assert group is None, "group argument must be None for now"
AssertionError: group argument must be None for now
```

Error code with group = None

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/paulm/Desktop/Github/git/YoutubeDownloader/main.py", line 179, in <module>
    recieve_input()
  File "C:/Users/paulm/Desktop/Github/git/YoutubeDownloader/main.py", line 37, in recieve_input
    video_download(parent_file, url)
  File "C:/Users/paulm/Desktop/Github/git/YoutubeDownloader/main.py", line 102, in video_download
    t1 = threading.Thread(l,target= download_multi, group = None, args=(l,check,parent_file,success,fail,total))
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'group'
```

Problem solved. The first thread had an typo and after fixing that it worked perfectly.

Comment: the ```t1 = threading.Thread(l,target=```  line is  not consistent with t2 and t3, typo ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AssertionError when threading in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349997/assertionerror-when-threading-in-python)

Comment: @bigdataolddriver lol u saved my day! How could I missed that! thx!!!!!

Comment: i update my comment as an answer and please accept it , so that your question does not show up in unaswered questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `t1 = threading.Thread(l,target=` line is not consistent with t2 and t3

the extra `l` was wrongly taken as the default value for group arg

typo?